# C++ Write to file not working in my addition to an existing application

Tags: c++, windows, bluetooth

I have an application that collects heart rate data and displays in in a GUI. I don't want to change anything about how the application runs, but want to save the data into a .csv file to use with data manipulation programs. The program is called BluetoothGattHeartRate. I am running the sample code found [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Bluetooth-Generic-5a99ef95).

My addition to the code is just

```
std::fstream theDump;
theDump.open("path/to/file", std::fstream::out);
if (theDump.is_open())
{
    theDump.write("ImHere", 6);
}
theDump.close();
```

inserted into the file called `HeartRateService.cpp` in the Shared directory in the `void HeartRateService::Characteristic_ValueChanged(GattCharacteristic^ sender, GattValueChangedEventArgs^ args)` function just before the call to  `ValueChangeCompleted(heartRateValue);`. I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio to edit and run the code, as the tutorial online says. This exact code succeeds in editing the file when run in an independent application, but it fails to open the file (I tested for this) when run in the Gatt sample code.

I don't expect that anyone has dealt with this before, but if by some miracle one of you has figured this out, please let me know how you fixed it.

Comment: It seams to be the os directory configuration problems check out all permisions or try to start your application in administrator mode. And try to use absolute file path if it works than something is wrong with your relative path.

Comment: What sort of application is it?  Modern, Desktop, ... ?  You could try Process Monitor (available from the MS web site) to confirm that it is attempting to open the right file, and this will also give you the exact error message from the operating system.